# Binding property of child property in qml

Tags: binding, properties, qml, qtquick2

I have this in a file named `ChildItem.qml`:

```
Item{
    property var childProperty
}
```

In another file named `ParentItem.qml`, I create the parent item and try to bind the `childProperty` to a property of the parent:

```
Item{
    property ChildItem childItem: null
    property var parentProperty
    childItem.childProperty: parentProperty
}
```

In `main.qml` I instantiate both objects and bind the parent's reference to the child:

```
ApplicationWindow{
    ChildItem{
        id: childID
    }
    ParentItem{
        id: parentID
        childItem: childID
    }
}
```

This gives me a `Cannot assign a value directly to a grouped property` error on the `childItem.childProperty: parentProperty` line. I work around this by changing the parent as follows:

```
Item {
    property ChildItem childItem: null
    property var parentProperty
    //childItem.childProperty: parentProperty
    onParentPropertyChanged: childItem.childProperty = parentProperty
}
```

But this looks and feels very artificial. Are there better ways to do this or other suggestions to change the structure in another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
childItem.childProperty: parentProperty
```

That's unfortunately not possible in QML syntax, even though it would be nice. The limitation is that bindings can only be defined within the declaration of the element itself, e.g. in this case within `ChildItem { ... }`. As a workaround, the [Binding](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-binding.html) element can be used in other places:

```
Binding {
    target: childItem
    property: "childProperty"
    value: parentProperty
}
```

But that, admittedly, is quite unwieldy as well.

I'd probably try to change the structure of my QML to avoid getting into this situation in the first place, maybe something like this:

```
ApplicationWindow{
    ChildItem{
        id: childID
        childProperty: parentID.parentProperty
    }
    ParentItem{
        id: parentID
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, `Binding` seems like it could potentially be a one-liner. The second option is unfortunately not possible in my scenario since the parent/child objects must be in their separate files for reusability.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, you have several errors in the code. Both logical and syntactical ones.

```
childItem.childProperty: parentProperty
```

This line isn't allowed here because of mixing declarative and imperative code. Also what will be if `childItem` is null? Replace it with:

```
onChildItemChanged: { 
    if(childItem)
        childItem.childProperty = parentProperty;
}
```

Next error:

```
childItem: childId
```

Just replce `childId` with `childID`.

Comment: How is that mixing declarative and imperative code ? I only see declarative code.

And why mixing wouldn't be allowed ?

Comment: @folibis `childItem.childProperty: parentProperty` is not imperative in the slightest. Your answer does not even work (and adds nothing over my workaround); it is only fired when the child is changed and not the `parentProperty` which is the correct logic.

Comment: Ok, you can change the event to `onParentPropertyChanged`. I've just noticed that line in the code you provided is syntactically incorrect. Assigning is imperative code here.